# How to get discontinuous element from a list/tuple in python?

Tags: python

I found a small question:
A function return values is a tuple containing 5 element. I want to 3 of them.

```
return=(1,2,3,4,5)
a=return[0]
b=return[2]
c=return[4]
```

Are there any simple slicing method?
Just like this fake code:

```
a,b,c=return[0,2,4]
```